# 111: Connection refused when trying apt update

Tags: 16.04, networking, apt, updates, dependencies

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I try to run `sudo apt update`, nothing gets updated, and the output is as follows:

```
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease Could not connect to 213.192.64.75:41258 (213.192.64.75). - connect (111: Connection refused) 
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Unable to connect to 213.192.64.75:41258: 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

No proxy running. No active firewall. Pinging the server in question works fine.

I am also unable to install any software packages due to `unmet dependencies`. My package manager seems to be completely messed up; not sure if the two are linked in any way so I made a separate question here for this: askubuntu.com/questions/1081041/apt-get-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Are you able to ping in terminal?

Comment: yes <satisfying required char count>

Comment: Please ask about the `unmet dependencies` in another question. Try to install any package from the terminal and paste the complete error message that you get as plain text. It would certainly be helpful to solve the `unmet dependencies` error so that you could install nmap.

Comment: ok sure I have a separate question for the unmet dependencies now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081041/apt-get-unmet-dependencies

Comment: @LostCrotchet What is the current status of this question? Did you ever figure out what was causing the `connect (111: Connection refused)` error messages? If this question did not lead to a firm conclusion can it be closed as non-reproducible?

Answer (score -1):

This might help you. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1844030.
You can also give this a try https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1844030.

Comment: You can include important points from the link provided since answers with links only aren't considered to be good answers.