# apt-get unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies

When I try to install any package with `apt` I get the following results:

Results of `sudo apt-get -f install nmap` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nmap : Depends: liblinear3 (>= 2.01+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: lua-lpeg but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ndiff but it is not going to be installed
 osbuddy : Depends: default-jre but it is not going to be installed or
                    java6-runtime or
                    java7-runtime
           Depends: jarwrapper (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: I would check your sources - the first is there for xenial & in the version it needs (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=liblinear3).  I'd do an `sudo apt update`; I'd look at where you are getting `nmap` from (`apt-cache policy nmap`), maybe even try the suggest fix (no errors requiring it are in your paste) and check you are running Ubuntu!  Do you get any errors for `sudo apt update`?  If yo do get errors, please provide those (added to your question thru edit) and possibly provide the command & output for `apt-cache policy nmap liblinear3`

Comment: The applications that are in the depends come from the `universe` repo.  Have you enabled the repo?  `sudo add-apt-repository universe` then run `sudo apt update`.  Then try the installation again.

Comment: There is not a package named osbuddy in 16.04, but I found an OSBuddy Debian package for RuneScape at https://rsbuddy.com/. osbuddy_1.2_all.deb has default-jre as a dependency in 16.04. default-jre is a package in the default 16.04 repositories, so that looks ago, but maybe you also have either RuneScape or RuneScape client installed and RuneScape is causing the unmet dependencies.

Comment: I visited the official [Download RuneScape](https://www.runescape.com/download) webpage and found this line which looks like it's causing a problem in 16.04: `echo "deb https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list.` The deb file for runescape-launcher needs to be edited and updated from 14.04 to 16.04. [I messed up my packages and can't get them to work. Dependencies missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045322/i-messed-up-my-packages-and-cant-get-them-to-work-dependencies-missing)

Comment: I am unable to do a sudo apt update - there is a separate question on this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080995/111-connection-refused-when-trying-apt-update?noredirect=1#comment1776485_1080995

Comment: @karel I followed through the steps of that link you send me to the other askubuntu pages and still no luck :( - similar errors as before, "connection refused"

Comment: @Terrance also tried your advice too, and same thing - connection refused / could not connect

Comment: Connection refused is not in your question.  You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1081041/edit) your question and copy and pasted all the exact errors you are getting.

Comment: after trying out a load of alternatives to fix my issue I think i've dug the hole deeper. I'm moving over to the ubuntu forums. :S